# sending emails in node js

Tags: node.js

After watching this video http://vimeo.com/26963384 on vimeo which was about how kue works,i have to ask how the code worked without installing any package to help send emails like node mailer.

Does the latest version of node js come with the capability to send emails?.

The code used looks like

```
jobs.create('email', {
    title: 'welcome email for tj'
  , to: 'tj@learnboost.com'
  , template: 'welcome-email'
}).save();
```

In the presentation,no package to send emails was added.

Comment: Sending emails is well outside of the 'out of the box' capabilities of node, but there is probably a library for it.  Check NPM.  Also, it's probably better to delegate it to a messaging agent rather than have node do all the work.

Comment: [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) is a very elaborate lib, [node-email](https://github.com/aheckmann/node-email) is simpler but still useful. Both can delegate to an MTA, which is indeed what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create SMTP transport
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        pass: '******'
    }
});

// transporter object for all e-mails

var mail = {
    from: 'XXX XXXX <XXX@gmail.com>', // sender address
    to: 'XXX@hotmail.com, XXX@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world </b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mail, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('Error : ' + error);
    }
    console.log('Mail sent: ' + info.response);

});
```

Comment: That's not what was asked. The OP wanted to know how it is possible without any other module and is already aware of node mailer.